# Progress bar design with text overlay

Tags: labels, progress-bar

I have a progress bar in my app where I want to display the amount done with a text overlay.

What I have is the text overlay begin centered in side the amount that is done so it looks like this

[image]

The problem is when the user hasnt done very much it looks like this (it should be 17/100, not 17/10 as is showed) but gets cut off

[image]

The other design alternative would be to always center the progress text, but then when the user is halfway done I going to run into the issue where part of the text is highlighted and part isnt which I think will look weird.

Should I make it so that even when the user has a small number complete to show more than the actual percent so they can see the whole number?

Or what are other design options

Comment: Is it a 1 to 100 bar always, or can the total number be something else than 100?

Comment: @Anders it can be any number, typically less than 1000 but user selects goal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try making the bar thinner. right now, the thick bar almost looks like a button, or some kind of slider control.

You can place the text just above. This way you don't have to worry about legibility, and you can add more descriptive text if you need to be descriptive or encouraging (such as describing the stages of a process).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It may not be necessary to put the two figures inside the progress bar:

[image]

The double progress bar can show the progress plus the total to be achieved:

[image]

The info bubble over the progress bar:

[image]